# xpath, xquery: how to find the first entry tag whose descendant is h?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I need to extract the first `<entry>` tag whose descendant is `<h>` in an xml file? My poor code is this:

```
$entry[1][//h]
```

But I don't think that works. Or how about this?

```
$entry[descendant::h][1]
```

sample.xml

```
<entry>
    <h>30</h>
</entry>
<entry>
    <m>50</m>
</entry>
<entry>
    <h>70</h>
</entry>
```

I want this:

```
<entry>
    <h>30</h>
</entry>
```

It's because that is the first which includes `<h>` tag as its descendant.

Comment: Can you provide an example document?

Answer (score 0):

This looks for an `entry` anywhere, that has the `h` descendant, and returns the first one:

```
(//entry[.//h])[1]
```